# Avoid Doctrine to return full related entity

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine

I am new in Symfony and I am trying to get all the records from my content table. It works but it also returns all the fields from the related entity.

```
$content = $this->contentRepository->findAll();
```

And here is what I get:

```
[{
    "id": 2,
    "field1": "xx",
    "field2": "xx",
    "field3": 22,
    "field4": {"id":1, "field1":"xx", ...},
    ....
},...]
```

On field4 I would like to get only the id as a value, instead of the whole object. Like if I were doing a SQL.
Reading from other places I found about lazy_loading but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You could use a data transfer object to only get certain fields https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#new-operator-syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getContentData(): array
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');

    $qb->select('c.id as id, IDENTITY(c.field4) as field4, c.field1 as field1, c.field2 as field2, c.field3 as field3');

    return  $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
}
```

But if you want to get an array of fields, it will be better to get the array of entities and serialize them by [JMSSerializerBundle](https://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle) or [The Serializer Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html)

Answer (score -1):

Just go to your `contentRepository` file and difine a function like this

```
public function getAllContentIds()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder();
    return $qb->select('id')
        ->from('YourBundleName:YourTableName')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

And then just use this function like this

```
$contentIds = $this->contentRepository->getAllContentIds();
```

Comment: What I mean is that doctrine returns the whole associated entity as the value of field4, I only need the id of that entity.

Comment: The other fields are fine

Comment: Consider updating your answer to match the question.  Which will probably be challenging since Doctrine does not support joining partial entities.